# Mi string da saltos de linea sin yo quererlo

Tags: python, string, lista

```
TINTA=[''' 
  _
|---|
|---|
|---|
|---|
|---|
|---|
 \ /
  ' ''']
TINTA2=['''
  _
|   |
|---|
|---|
|---|
|---|
|---|
 \ /
  ' ''']
TINTA3=['''
  _
|   |
|   |
|---|
|---|
|---|
|---|
 \ /
  ' ''']
TINTA4=['''
   _
 |   |
 |   |
 |   |
 |---|
 |---|
 |---|
  \ /
  ' ''']
TINTA5=['''
  _
|   |
|   |
|   |
|   |
|---|
|---|
 \ /
  ' ''']
TINTA6=['''
  _
|   |
|   |
|   |
|   |
|   |
|---|
 \ /
  ' ''']
TINTA7=['''
 _
|   |
|   |
|   |
|   |
|   |
|   |
 \ /
 ' ''']

print("Introduce el texto para calcular la tinta que has usado: ")
 texto=input()

if len(texto)<40:
  print(TINTA)
elif len(texto) >= 40:
  print(TINTA2) 
elif len(texto) >= 60:
  print(TINTA3) 
elif len(texto) >= 80:
  print(TINTA4) 
elif len(texto) >= 100:
  print(TINTA5) 
elif len(texto) >= 120:
  print(TINTA6) 
elif len(texto) >= 140:
  print(TINTA7)
```

Cuando imprimo me sale lo siguiente:

```
Programa de cálculo de tinta...
Introduce el texto para calcular la tinta que has usado: python
[" \n\t  _\n\t|---|\n\t|---|\n\t|---|\n\t|---|\n\t|---|\n\t|---|\n\t \\  /\n\t  ' "]
```

Answer (score 2):

El problema es que cada una de las variables que has definido, por ejemplo esta:

```
TINTA=[''' 
  _
|---|
|---|
|---|
|---|
|---|
|---|
 \ /
  ' ''']
```

no es una cadena, sino una lista, debido a los corchetes que lo encierran. Eso sí, es una lista con un solo elemento, lo que no tiene mucho sentido.

Puedes quitar los corchetes que has puesto en todas estas definiciones, y entonces `print(TINTA)` funcionará como esperas.

También puedes dejar los corchetes, pero en ese caso `print(TINTA)` imprimirá la lista, con el resultado que observas, y lo que tú quieres es imprimir sólo el primer elemento, para lo que deberías usar `print(TINTA[0])` (y así con los restantes casos).

Por otro lado, la lógica de los `if` está mal, ya que si el número de caracteres es menor de 40 mostrará `TINTA`, mientras que si es mayor o igual a 40 mostrará siempre `TINTA2`, sin importar ya que sea mayor o menor que 60, 80, 100, etc.

Entiendo que debería ser así:

```
if len(texto) < 40:
  print(TINTA)
elif len(texto) < 60:
  print(TINTA2)
elif len(texto) < 80:
  print(TINTA3)
elif len(texto) < 100:
  print(TINTA4)
elif len(texto) < 120:
  print(TINTA5)
elif len(texto) < 140:
  print(TINTA6)
else:
  print(TINTA7)
```

### Sugerencia de mejora

Todas esas variables `TINTA`, `TINTA2`, `TINTA3`, etc. están pidiendo que las conviertas en una sola, llamada `TINTA`, que sea una lista con varios elementos, siendo cada elemento cada una de las cadenas. Así:

```
TINTA=['''
  _
|---|
|---|
|---|
|---|
|---|
|---|
 \ /
  ' ''',
'''
  _
|   |
|---|
|---|
|---|
|---|
|---|
 \ /
  ' ''',
'''
  _
|   |
|   |
|---|
|---|
|---|
|---|
 \ /
  ' ''',
'''
  _
|   |
|   |
|   |
|---|
|---|
|---|
 \ /
  ' ''',
 '''
  _
|   |
|   |
|   |
|   |
|---|
|---|
 \ /
  ' ''',
 '''
  _
|   |
|   |
|   |
|   |
|   |
|---|
 \ /
  ' ''',
 '''
  _
|   |
|   |
|   |
|   |
|   |
|   |
 \ /
  ' ''']
```

Esta es una lista con 7 elementos, y para acceder a cada uno de ellos usaríamos `TINTA[0]`, `TINTA[1]`, etc. hasta `TINTA[6]` que sería el último.

Ahora, para elegir cuál de los elementos del array pintar, basta hacer unos cálculos, en lugar de los condicionales:

```
print("Introduce el texto para calcular la tinta que has usado: ")
texto=input()
longitud = len(texto)
elemento = min(max(0, (longitud-20)//20), len(TINTA)-1)
print(TINTA[elemento])
```

El elemento del array a mostrar se obtiene restando 20 a la longitud y después haciendo la división entera entre 20. Puedes comprobar, por ejemplo, que para `longitud=30` eso saldría `(30-20)//20  = 10//20 = 0`. Para `longitud=45` saldría `(45-20)//20 = 25//20 = 1`, etc.

En general funciona para cualquier longitud, salvo para las menores de 20 que saldría negativo, o para las muy grandes, que podría salir mayor de `6`, y por tanto fuera de los límites de la lista `TINTA`. Por eso utilizo las funciones `min()` y `max()`, para asegurar que el resultado esté siempre entre 0 y 6.